# "Expected type specifier before class" error in C++

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to execute a linked list in C++. I have a separate list.h file with Node class defined. My list.cpp file contains the definitions of functions for linked list. There are no issues with the header files and Ifndef files. I am getting this "**Expected type specifier before Node**" error in a few instructions where I have defined or initialized a node in list.cpp. Example code snippet is given below:

```
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::Insert(T element)
{
    Node <T> *n= new Node(T element);
}
```

P.s I dont have much knowledge about template type declarations. I have seen many such related answers on this site but none of them helped me for this type of error.

Comment: It should probably be `new Node<T>(element);`

Comment: @Steve314 I have mentioned already that I am not familiar with template type implementations. How can we declare a Node by using "LinkedList<T>::Node *n= new Node(T element);" ??

Comment: @VTT After implementing what you suggested the compiler has given another error "expected primary-expression before 'element'".

Comment: @Steve314 I have a separate list.h file that has the code for Node class. I am just defining linked list functions in list.cpp. So I need to declare nodes in this part to use them...

Comment: I'm not a big fan of template programming in C++ (primarily because the syntax is atrocious).  BUT, I find it easiest to do by first making a non-template implementation, get that working, and then converting that into a templated version.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the following outline and corrected your intended code. Note however, that using raw built-in pointers is considered bad style since C++11 since it makes so called memory leaks easy, even for your learning exercise of implementing a bad version of `std::list`. Consider my improvement below.

```
template <typename T>
class LinkedList{

    struct Node{
        Node (T t) {}
    };
public:
    void Insert(T element);
};

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::Insert(T element)
{
    Node *n= new Node(element);
}
```

---

Spot-Improvement

```
#include <memory>
    struct Node{
        Node (T t)  {}
        std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
    };

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::Insert(T element)
{
    //If you got a C++>=14 implementation
    auto n = std::make_unique<Node>(element);
    //If you have to stick to C++11
    auto n = std::unique_ptr<Node>{new Node(element)};
}
```

Comment: One issue is (as with OPs original, and I'm sure you're aware but some readers may not be) that the pointer to the node node is only stored as a raw pointer in a local variable which then immediately falls out of scope - it's not a list, it's a memory leak. There's a distinct lack of member variables, which should ideally be of type `unique_ptr<Node>` (unless using raw pointers is required for some reason).

Comment: I know, he should stick to RAII and DRY principles, but I guess the author is a student who has to implement a linked list. Often students are confused when you introduce much new stuff at once, and also professors are getting angry when they don't understand why you use `auto`, `std::unique_ptr` and so on. 

Nevertheless you're right, I will add a second solution, to nudge the newbie into a more reliant style.